# Show that $\{x^{2k}\}_{k\ge 0}$ is complete in $C([0,1])$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

This is Exercise 2.4 in A Basis Theory Primer, Christopher Heil. I am just reading this book and not a homework.

> The Weierstrauss Approximation Theorem implies that $\{x^{k}\}_{k\ge 0}$ is complete in $C[0,1]$. Show that $\{x^{2k}\}_{k\ge 0}$ is also complete in $C[0,1]$.

In the book it is defined $\{a_k\}\subset X$ is complete in a normed linear space $X$ if the set of all finite linear combination of $\{a_k\}$ is dense in $X$.

**Attempt:** It suffices to show that given arbitrary $\epsilon>0$ and $x^k$, with some $x^{2\ell}$ we have
$$
\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|x^k-x^{2\ell}|<\epsilon.
$$
If $k$ is even, we can let $\ell:=\frac{k}2$. But if $k$ is odd, I am stuck and not sure if this approach is a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $f\in C([0,1])$. As $g(u)=f(\sqrt{u})$ is also in $C([0,1])$, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exist a polynomial $P$
such that for all $u\in [0,1]$, we have $|g(u)-P(u)|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: How do we know that $g$ needs only even powers in $P$?

Comment: We want to approximate $f$, not $g$. In the inequality above, for an $x\in [0,1]$, put $u=x^2$.

Comment: Oh! Thanks. +1....

Comment: @zoli You are welcome